# Including to different headers to a same page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have this file named `file-not-found.php` and with different headers.. what i want to do is change the header depending on the route name or url segment

In **CodeIgniter** i can do this

```
function blah(){
    include('layout.registered.header')
    include('layout.file-not-found')
}

function unregistered(){
    include('layout.unregistered.header')
    include('layout.file-not-found')
}
```

now.. How can I obtain this in Laravel Blade Templating without using controllers..
I am only using routes and views

I tried the method below and it calls the extends in **IF** and also calls the extends at the **ELSE** so it display 2 layouts at the same time

**file-not-found.blade.php**

```
@if (Route::currentRouteName() == 'file-not-found')
    @extends('layouts.unregistered')

@else
    @extends('layouts.registered')

@endif
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/file-not-found', array('as' => 'file-not-found', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.new.file-not-found');
}));


Route::get('registered/file-not-found', array('as' => 'registered', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.new.file-not-found');
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
@extends(Route::currentRouteName() == 'file-not-found' ? 'layouts.unregistered' : 'layouts.registered')
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Laravel are you using? I believe since version 4.1 you need to access the current route using Route::current()->getName() instead of Route::currentRouteName().

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2919. It appears the main docs have not been updated

Comment: It (`Route::currentRouteName()`) works `4.1.9`, tested.

Comment: Hmmm... odd, the [upgrade](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade#upgrade-4.1) documentation from 4.0 to 4.1 says "The current route is now accessed via Route::current() instead of Route::getCurrentRoute()". Guess both are still supported. I like your trick though for the single extends... I'll use that one :)

Comment: There is a `current()` method available tho.